# SQL query to find count of distinct values among two columns

Tags: mysql

Given the following table named demo:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | bag_1 | bag_2  |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | Alpha | Alpha  |
|  2 | Alpha | Beta   |
|  3 | Beta  | Beta   |
|  4 | Beta  | Omega  |
|  5 | Beta  | Delta  |
|  6 | Beta  | Sigma  |
|  7 | Gamma | Alpha  |
|  8 | Gamma | Lambda |
|  9 | Gamma | Omega  |
+----+-------+--------+
```

How can I find the count of distinct values in both bag_1 and bag_2 columns?

(Expected count = 7)

Note: Original table has ~1.8 Million rows, so joins never completed successfully.

Comment: What is this??? You only posted the question and answer. Then why did you post the question?

Comment: @Ullas: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @eggyal : But here the situation is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `UNION ALL` to collect all possible values, then `COUNT(DISTINCT bag)` will do the rest, like so:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bag) from (SELECT bag_1 AS bag FROM demo UNION ALL SELECT bag_2 AS bag FROM demo) a;`

`+---------------------+
| count(distinct bag) |
+---------------------+
|                   7 |
+---------------------+`

Edit:
curtsy of @Tim Biegeleisen and @eggyal, a shorter form would be:

`SELECT COUNT(*) from (SELECT bag_1 AS bag FROM demo UNION SELECT bag_2 AS bag FROM demo) a;`

Comment: What is this??? You only posted the question and answer. Then why did you post the question?

Comment: You could use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, which might throw out some records, thereby making the query a bit faster.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen, and would have just done `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT bag_1 FROM demo UNION SELECT bag_2 FROM demo) a`.

Comment: @eggyal Careful: I'm not sure if `UNION` removes duplicates from within the same table, rather than _between_ the two tables being unioned.  But `UNION ALL` should make the table on which `COUNT` is run smaller.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It does.

Comment: @Ullas I was making attempts while writing the answer, once I found the answer, I posted both question and answer. I.e., didn't want to keep answer to myself so that others might find it useful.

Comment: thanks all for your input, just made a quick experiment with both forms of queries, and both return within ~10.5 seconds (on my 1.8M row table).

Comment: @has981: You might consider adding two indexes, one over each of the bag columns.

Comment: @eggyal, thanks for you input on this. I think that makes sense. Notice the original table I'm working with is more complex (I have to match against other columns) which rather complicates the query. But anyways, this was a one-time query, so it was ok for me to get the answer within 10sec ;). But really, thanks for your input on this, I learned something new from you.